# Publication key value change

Tags: dxa, content-manager, sites-9, dxa2.2

Blueprint has 000,100,110,200,400 and pages on 400 already active on acceptance.

**100 Master** publication has current wrong value for **Publication Key**.

1. Changing "DxaMaster" to "DxaMasterCommon" what will happen?
2. Do we have to publish all again on 400 level?
3. Is there any impact on environments with import/export if
   publication key differs?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publication Key is a part of Publication metadata, it has no direct relation with the publishing content, so republishing of content wouldn't be required. For a DXA application, you probably need to republish `Publish Settings` page only.

AFIK it (changing) has no impact on import/export either.

However, do make sure to update any mappings in Topology Manager that uses the old Publication Key value, see SDL docs: [Editing a Publication](https://docs.sdl.com/792149/677399/sdl-tridion-sites-9/editing-a-publication)